# Send automatic emails from CSV attachment

Tags: csv, email, outlook, email-attachments

Each day I receive an email with a CSV/excel attachment With a list of email addresses. I’d like to automatically take these addresses and mail an email template to all of them. The catch is, it has to be done on a work computer so I can’t download any additional programs to help with it. This will need to be done with native Windows apps. I’ve tried using VBA without success (I’m not well versed). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro or COM add-in if you are going to distribute the solution to multiple machines. Basically, you need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.

```
Private Sub Applicaition_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mai As Object
    
    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
    MsgBox mai.Subject
    
End Sub
```

In the event handler, you need to save the attached Excel file to the hard drive. Then you can automate Excel to open the file and read its content for creating a new item based on a template saved. Read more about these actions in the following articles:

- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)